# Problemas al mostrar algunos caracteres especiales

Tags: php, html

Mi problema consiste en que en un panel de administración se debe mostrar dominios , usuarios y contraseñas. El caso es que las contraseñas tienen caraacteres especiales, entre ellos `<` y `>`. Y a la hora de mostrar todo lo que esté entre esos caracteres los toma como etiquetas HTML. ¿ Hay alguna funcion de *PHP5* para que muestre las contraseñas de forma literal ?

Comment: Si estás mostrando las contraseñas a partir de print o echo, te recomiendo que lo cambies y uses un <input type="text"/> en su lugar. Aún así, no es nada recomendable mostrar información de las contraseñas en ninguna web, por seguridad

Comment: no, lo que pasa es que es un panel de administracion, donde muestra usuarios contraseñas y más datos, todo está en privado y con control de usuarios, pero gracias por la sugerencia, y los muestro con un framwork de PHP muuuy antiguo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La función que buscas es [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Te muestro su uso con un ejemplo:

```
<?php

$password = "<123456>?.$<span>";

// No muestra el <span>
echo $password, "<br/>", PHP_EOL;

// Muestra todos los caracteres, incluso el <span>
echo htmlspecialchars($password), PHP_EOL;
```

Aquí un ejemplo en línea: [Ejemplo](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn$password%20=%20%22%3C123456%3E?.$%3Cspan%3E%22;%5Cn//No%20muestra%20el%20%3Cspan%3E%5Cnecho%20$password;%5Cnecho%20%22%3Cbr%3E%22;%5Cn//Muestra%20todos%20los%20caracteres%20incluso%20el%20%3Cspan%3E%5Cnecho%20htmlspecialchars($password);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)

Comment: Gracias, buena respuesta, aunque ya he implementado otra `htmlentities()` no sé si te suene jeje pero de igual manera gracias :)